# spatial degeneracy in the states of atoms and molecules

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I would like to know if the exact ground state of a closed-shell atom or molecule can have a spatial degeneracy. If we ignore relativistics effects, the Hamiltonian of the system $H$ commutes with the Spin  operators $S^{2}$ and $S_{z}$, so, to each eigenstate of $H$, there are another $2S + 1$ eigenstates that have the same energy. In the case of a closed-shell system, $S = 0$ and there are no spin degeneracy. However, my doubt is about spatial degeneracy, that is, if it can exist two states $\Psi$ and $\Psi'$ with the same energy eigenvalue that have the same spin. (in this case, $H$ is the full Hamiltonian, that includes electron-electron interaction)

Comment: The nearest to your requirement would seem to be a particle on a ring where $\psi(\theta)=e^{\pm ni\theta}/\sqrt{2\pi}$ and where $n=0,\pm1,\pm2\cdots$ and when $n>0$